# DB2-Find the count of number of occurrences of different values for each primary key in a table

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I have a table like

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | ABCD |
| 2 | ABC |

Column 2 can either have ABC or ABCD
Now I want to find the count for values in column 2 for each ID

| ID | count (ABC) | count (ABCD) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

How to write DB2 query to get the output in the above format for count?

Comment: There are a lot of similar answered questions you might find with the `db2 pivot` search string.

Comment: If you have several occurences, how can it be a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

```
Select ID, sum(decode(value, 'ABC',1,0)) as count_abc
     , sum(decode(value, 'ABCD',1,0)) as count_abcd 
from table 
group by ID
```